# Using SRV Records from Consul

Tags: dns, playback, consul, service-discovery, srv

I have recently inherited a micro-services architecture deployed on AWS ECS using Application Load Balancers and Route-53 to handle service discovery and decided that consul would be simpler and cheaper for this task.

Our port mappings for services are dynamic and handled by ECS so A records won't work for DNS as they are missing the port.

**What is the typical approach for using SRV records for DNS within services?**

To build on that is consul the right tool for this job or is this a sign of some other underlying architectural issue as it seems that SRV records are not a standard use-case.

Comment: please accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

SRV records are useful for applications or scripts that can query them (e.g. client-side load balancing).

You can use Consul for your microservices setup together with a Consul aware load balancer such as https://traefik.io/ or https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio. - put an AWS load balancer in front of multiple instances of fabio/traefik/... and route all traffic to it.

Comment: In this case I believe you need a TCP/UDP reverse proxy , which would rule out Traefik which will just handle HTTP traffic.

Comment: I have it as an example, you can use fabio, or  haproxy/nginx with dynamically compiled config files from consul (https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template)